# Increasing number generator using ScalaCheck gens

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I want to simulate device readings using a ScalaCheck generators. The property of the readings is that every subsequent reading should be greater than the previous one. I have written some code using vars but would like to achieve this using higher order functions on the Gens and by composing generators. Does anyone have a better suggestion?

```
import org.scalacheck.Gen

class DeviceReadingGenerator(deviceId: DeviceId = Generate.deviceId.sample.get) {
  private var timeSlot = Generate.epochInSec.sample.get
  private var reading = Gen.choose(0, 100).sample.get

  def nextReading(): Reading = {
    val gen: Gen[Event] = for {
      r <- Generate.event
      time <- Gen.const(30)
      cons <- Generate.consumption
    } yield {
      timeSlot += time
      reading += cons
      r
        .copy(timeSlot = timeSlot)
        .copy(readingWh = reading)
    }
    Reading(deviceId, gen.sample.get)
  }
}
```